# How do I manually install cx_Oracle rpm?

Tags: python, linux, installation, rpm

I don't have root privileges. I have downloaded `cx_Oracle-5.1.2-10g-py26-1.i386.rpm` and I want to install it. How can I install it without root privileges?

Comment: You can't do that in a general case. For some specific packages (e.g. if it's a python extension) you can try unpacking the rpm with `rpm2cpio *.rpm | cpio -i` (somewhere within you `$HOME`), and then make python recognize its additional directories as valid path for searching modules (I don't know the details here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go: I have installed in `/home/spatel/cx`

```
[spatel@us04 ~]$ rpm -ivh --root /home/spatel/cx cx_Oracle-5.1-11g-py32-1.i386.rpm --relocate /usr=/home/spatel/cx
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:cx_Oracle              ########################################### [100%]
```

Here are my modules:

```
[spatel@us04 ~]$ ls -l ~/cx/lib/python3.2/site-packages/
total 276
-rw-r--r-- 1 spatel spatel    896 Mar 19  2011 cx_Oracle-5.1-py3.2.egg-info
-rwxr-xr-x 1 spatel spatel 273264 Mar 19  2011 cx_Oracle.cpython-32mu.so
```

Set your python path

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/home/spatel/cx/lib/python3.2/site-packages")
>>> print (sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib64/python24.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.4', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages', '/home/spatel/cx/lib/python3.2/site-packages']
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but the download page doesn't have any rpm for Python 3.5.1. Do you know how to workaround this? (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/5.2.1)

Answer (score 3):

well, there are 2 possibilities:

1. install rpm without being root: http://ajaya.name/?p=6353
2. download source and install it wherever you want (source can be found at: http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/ (Source Code Only)

I'd suggest 2 option if you compiled something already

Comment: The first link is not working anymore. I'm trying the second option but I don't have permission to do the build install part. Do you know how to install locally in a virtual environment? Thanks.